# I was trying to make my own msgs in ROS in a separate package and then accessing the msg from another package using a node a publisher on a topic

Tags: c++, ros, robotics

The code is working and I am getting my desired result but still facing this error

#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/sparsh28/catkin_WS/src/my_robot_controller/src/my_robot_publisher.cpp).

My Code is:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <my_robot_msgs/HardwareStatus.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_robot_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<my_robot_msgs::HardwareStatus>("/my_robot/hd_st", 10);
    ROS_INFO("Node Started");
    ros::Rate rate(5);

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        my_robot_msgs::HardwareStatus msg;
        msg.temperature=30;
        msg.are_motors_up=true;
        msg.debug_message="Ok";
        pub.publish(msg);
        rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

this is the code and I am facing the error in line 2 of the main code

c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "browse": {
        "databaseFilename": "${default}",
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
      },
      "includePath": [
        "/opt/ros/noetic/include/**",
        "/usr/include/**",
        "~/catkin_WS/devel/include/my_robot_msgs;/opt/ros/noetic/**"
      ],
      "name": "ROS",
      "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
      "cStandard": "gnu11",
      "cppStandard": "c++14"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

settings.json file

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages"
    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages"
    ]
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code for this

Comment: I'm not a user of VS Code, but check their docs to see if you want the `**` on the end of the paths (eg `/opt/ros/noetic/include/**`). The `*` are generally wildcard operators, so you may be telling the system to include all of the folders inside `/opt/ros/noetic/include/` rather than `/opt/ros/noetic/include/` itself.

Comment: [Looking here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference), the sample include path is specified as `"/another/path"`. No `*`s in sight.

Comment: Reading the above link further, it looks like I'm right: *Searching on these paths is not recursive. Specify `**` to indicate recursive search. For example,` ${workspaceFolder}/**` will search through all subdirectories while `${workspaceFolder}` will not*. Remove the `**`s from the paths in your config file.

Comment: Hey @user458130, thanks for the help. The problem is solved now and your documents on VS Code helped.

I added the following line in my include path and voila the error disappeared.

                                "~/catkin_WS/devel/include/**"

Once again thanks for the help. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

```
"~/catkin_WS/devel/include/**"
```

I added this line in my config file in includePath section and the problem was solved.

Previously my code was working fine and I was getting my desired result too but an error was constantly popping up on the include path of my msg package.
Ultimately, the my code would produce result as that package was added as a dependency so it was accessed and the result was produced but a definite path to the header file was defined. So the above code or the line defines the exact path of that header file.